# Does the phrase "fit in" make sense to non-native English speakers?

Tags: ambiguity

I was planning to use the expression "fit in" in a presentation -- as in "how do you fit in [to the group]?"

The audience will include people who speak English as a second language. There will be a wide range of first languages.

Someone has suggested that the phrase "fit in" might not be universally understood. Do you think it works? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works. Being a non-native English speaker, I can assure you it will be understood. I study amongst hundreds of students who speak English as a second language and they often use the phrase 'fit in'. You can use it without any hesitation!